# Datatable Pagination "Next" enabled when showing records "All".How to disable it?

Tags: jquery, datatables, pagination

Currently am working on datatable plugin 1.9.4. Below is datatable intialization code:

```
oTable = $('#tablename').dataTable({
      "aLengthMenu": [
              [5, 15, 20, -1],
              [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
          ],

      "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
      "oLanguage": {    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
          "sSearch" : "Search records:",
          "oPaginate": {
              "sPrevious": "Prev",
              "sNext": "Next"
          }
      },
 });
```

Problem:

When Selecting show 5,15,20 records "Next" is disabled but when i tried to show "All" the Next is still enabled.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? everything you posted is correct so it has to be something else not listed

Comment: am using bootstrap framework.you can see the same issue in this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tNXnB/1/)."Next" is in blue color but when clicking on Next nothing happpens.I want it in Grey color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is that jsfiddle you linked updated with the fixed code http://jsfiddle.net/tNXnB/6/

```
    /* Set the defaults for DataTables initialisation */
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-xs-6'l><'col-xs-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
} );




/* Default class modification */
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline",
        "sFilterInput": "form-control input-sm",
        "sLengthSelect": "form-control input-sm"
} );


/* API method to get paging information */
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
{
        return {
                "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
                "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
                "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
                "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
                "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
                "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                        0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
                "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                        0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
        };
};


/* Bootstrap style pagination control */
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
        "bootstrap": {
                "fnInit": function( oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw ) {
                        var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
                        var fnClickHandler = function ( e ) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                if ( oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action) ) {
                                        fnDraw( oSettings );
                                }
                        };

                        $(nPaging).append(
                                '<ul class="pagination">'+
                                        '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; '+oLang.sPrevious+'</a></li>'+
                                        '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">'+oLang.sNext+' &rarr; </a></li>'+
                                '</ul>'
                        );
                        var els = $('a', nPaging);
                        $(els[0]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "previous" }, fnClickHandler );
                        $(els[1]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "next" }, fnClickHandler );
                },

                "fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnDraw ) {
                        var iListLength = 5;
                        var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
                        var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
                        var i, ien, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf=Math.floor(iListLength/2);

                        if ( oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                                iStart = 1;
                                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                        }
                        else if ( oPaging.iPage <= iHalf ) {
                                iStart = 1;
                                iEnd = iListLength;
                        } else if ( oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages-iHalf) ) {
                                iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                        } else {
                                iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                                iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
                        }

                        for ( i=0, ien=an.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                                // Remove the middle elements
                                $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();

                                // Add the new list items and their event handlers
                                for ( j=iStart ; j<=iEnd ; j++ ) {
                                        sClass = (j==oPaging.iPage+1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                                        $('<li '+sClass+'><a href="#">'+j+'</a></li>')
                                                .insertBefore( $('li:last', an[i])[0] )
                                                .bind('click', function (e) {
                                                        e.preventDefault();
                                                        oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)-1) * oPaging.iLength;
                                                        fnDraw( oSettings );
                                                } );
                                }

                                // Add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
                                if ( oPaging.iPage === 0 ) {
                                        $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                                } else {
                                        $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                                }

                                if ( oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages-1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0 ) {
                                        $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                                } else {
                                        $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
} );


/*
 * TableTools Bootstrap compatibility
 * Required TableTools 2.1+
 */
if ( $.fn.DataTable.TableTools ) {
        // Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
        $.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
                "container": "DTTT btn-group",
                "buttons": {
                        "normal": "btn btn-default",
                        "disabled": "disabled"
                },
                "collection": {
                        "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
                        "buttons": {
                                "normal": "",
                                "disabled": "disabled"
                        }
                },
                "print": {
                        "info": "DTTT_print_info modal"
                },
                "select": {
                        "row": "active"
                }
        } );

        // Have the collection use a bootstrap compatible dropdown
        $.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
                "collection": {
                        "container": "ul",
                        "button": "li",
                        "liner": "a"
                }
        } );
}
```

This is for twitter bootstrap 3.0 css, the full repo of datatables twitter bootstrap 3 code can be found here https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/integration/bootstrap/3/index.html

Comment: Its working.So when using bootstrap datatables is there any mandatory using all the above functions for sPaginationType:"bootstrap". But if i use sPaginationType:"full_numbers" also Next Prev buttons are enabled [Fiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/7wSbY/3/).I just tried with some css styles [Added css link](http://jsfiddle.net/srj9a/) works fine. Please Suggest me on datatable paginationType in bootstrap?

Comment: In order to go beyond default pagination with bootstrap, that code would have to be modified, here is a link on how some have accomplished this in bootsrap 2 http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/44935 you would have to migrate and merry that example with the bootsrap 3 pagination code