# How to put pagination on top using datatable.js in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

When we are using datatable.js then it will be displayed pagination at bottom. But we need pagination at top besides filters.

[image]

And also hide pagination when length is to short. I mean default pagination length is 10. If table have total records below 10, that time pagination will not be displayed. When table have more than 10 records that time pagination will be displayed.

Any one have any idea? Hows we can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this property

```
"sDom": '<"top"pi>rt<"bottom"fl><"clear">'
```

Comment: This parameters is working for pagination put on top. But how we disable next and previous button when record is less than length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071436/datatable-pagination-next-enabled-when-showing-records-all-how-to-disable-it/20098443#20098443

Comment: Its not same as my requirements. I need when total records are 10 and display length is 10. That time i don't need to display previous and next button. If total records more than 10, that time i need to display next and previous button.